# When a new primary is elected that is not listed in the app's hosts list, does MongoDB still allow writes?

Tags: mongodb

In an app using a MongoDB driver (for Node.js), I've listed 3 databases: `db-01`, `db-02` and `db-03`.

I add a new database to the replica-set: `db-04`.

Accidentally, the `db-04` database gets elected to be the new primary.

Will the app still be able to do writes, or should I have listed `db-04` in the hosts list of the app's MongoDB driver configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by "database" you mean "member" or "node" instead. You cannot have a database per replica member that's not a replica set. I will assume that you meant members.

If an available member is in the list then yes, the MongoDB driver will use any member of the replica set to understand the entirety of the set. So even if you do not explicitly connect to a primary in your code it will still seek the primary of the set by calling an `isMaster` on the node you do connect to. It will then use that in the application.

Comment: To make this a bit more clear (@Sammaye Forgive me!): If the MongoDriver connects to a replica set member for the first time, it is told the current status of the replica set, including it's (visible) members. The reason why you should have multiple members of the replica set in your connection description is simply that if the driver can't establish it's first connection to the first member in said description (for example because it is down), it will try to connect to the next, thus enabling the driver to connect even when one member is unreachable.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg exactly, I left that out since I didn't want to bog down the answer too much but your addition is a valuable one